# Are C function calls without variables precompiled or evaluated at run time?

Tags: c, printf, conditional-statements

Essentially, if I have code:

```
void main(void){
   foo(1,3);
}
```

Where foo is:

```
void foo(int x, int y){
   if(x==0) return;
   else if (x==1){
      if(y==0) printf("hello, world");
      else if (y==2) printf("goodbye.");
      else if (y==3) printf("no.");
      else return;
   }
   else return;
}
```

Will the conditionals (assuming they apply) be evaluated at run time, or will the 'printf' statements in this case simply compile in the executable, essentially with the compiler evaluating the conditionals?

Comment: `void main(void)` is wrong, it's `int main(void)` if your compiler is not telling you that it's wrong, then you might need to configure your compiler warnings or change the compiler.

Comment: This is obviously a trivial case, I'm asking as im working on an embedded system where real-time performance is a priority

Comment: Depends on the compiler, compiler settings, possibly whether both the functions are in the same compilation unit (or if you have PGO)... The C standard allows a compiler to do optimizations, but essentially none are mandatory.

Comment: If you let the compiler optimize the code, then it will be optimized, but you should be using a `switch` anyway, don't you?.

Comment: @iharob, because my comment wasn't in reply to you: for this application, the code is running on an embedded system with JeOS, I don't care if/when main returns, and if so what because my code will always begin running again from the top of 'main()'.

Comment: https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/LinkTimeOptimization

Comment: Try looking at your disassembly and see what is generated.  Making your function `inline` will encourage the compiler to substitute those constants into the function and optimize away the conditional.

Comment: @iharob, again, good point, but I'm working in something of a special case, firstly my particular conditionals will contain sfr references, which [SDCC] (http://sdcc.sourceforge.net) does not like to put in arrays (or array-like structures like switch statements). I tried to make my particular question as general case as possible. On top of that, I may want to evaluate multiple conditions (everything will not always be 'else if'). This would be non-trivial for me to implement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Will the conditionals (assuming they apply) be evaluated at run time,
>   or will the 'printf' statements in this case simply compile in the
>   executable, essentially with the compiler evaluating the conditionals?

Compiler is free to emit whatever code it wants as long as the semantics remain the same<sup>citation needed</sup>. Most compilers have configurable optimization levels which control how aggressive they can be in transforming source code. In case of `gcc`, the relevant flag is `-O`*x*.

The only way to see what code is emitted, is to inspect it oneself. In case of `gcc` you can use `-S` flag, that outputs generated assembler.

In your program, `gcc -O0 -S opt.c` (no optimizations) yield following:

```
main:
.LFB1:
    .cfi_startproc
    pushq   %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
    .cfi_offset 6, -16
    movq    %rsp, %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa_register 6
    movl    $3, %esi
    movl    $1, %edi
    call    foo #        <---
    popq    %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa 7, 8
    ret
    .cfi_endproc
```

Whereas `gcc -O1 -S opt.c` and higher optimization levels result in:

```
.LC2:
    .string "no."
(...)
main:
.LFB12:
    .cfi_startproc
    subq    $8, %rsp
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
    movl    $.LC2, %edi
    movl    $0, %eax
    call    printf  #    <----
    addq    $8, %rsp
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 8
    ret
    .cfi_endproc
```

Answer (score 1):

The compiler cannot interpret the code in function `foo()`. It will generate the code for `if`s and `printf()`s into the function's body.

There are several reasons it doesn't do that. One of them is the linkage of the function. It is not declared as `static` and that means it may be used in other `.c` files; the compiler cannot just guess what are the values of its arguments on the actual call.

And calling it with different arguments to output different things is the reason you wrote the function in the first place.

Depending on the compiler and the optimization switches you use when you invoke it, it can inline the call to `foo(1,3)`. Inlining means the compiler replaces the call to the function with the code of the function's body. In this case it can optimize the inlined code because it knows the values of the arguments and it can tell which `printf()` runs; it removes the `if`s and the other `printf()`s because they are dead code and instead of a call to `foo(1,3)` it generates the code for `printf("no.");`. But this can happen only because the arguments of your function call are constant (i.e. they are known at the compile time).

However, even in this case, the code for function is still generated. 
If the call `foo(1,3);` is the only one call to the function and the compiler is able to inline it, the function's code will be removed (will be ignored because it is not called) by the linker, when it generates the final executable.

Check the command line switches of your compiler for optimization flags. Also check how you can instruct it to generate an assembly file (with comments) to see what code it generates (you can see there if it inlines the call to `foo(1,3)` or not).

Answer (score 0):

After disassembly the foo function like this:

```
011714AE  push        3  
011714B0  push        1  
011714B2  call        foo (11711D6h)
```

that is mean C function push variables into memory first after that get back from esp for evaluate at run time

Comment: This is surely implementation specific and depend upon the compiler, the operating system, the optimization flags.

Comment: ofcouse depend upon the compiler but Iam sure to you all compilers operation give the same result. that its evaluate at run time if you don't change your code.